# Como obtener la fecha del próximo lunes y ponerlo en un input text

Tags: javascript

Por medio de JavaScript necesito obtener la fecha del lunes mas cercano a la fecha actual, por ejemplo hoy martes 26 de abril, necesito obtener la fecha del próximo lunes que es 1 de mayo y mostrar esa fecha en un input text.

```
const tiempoTranscurrido = Date.now();
```

Este es para sacar la fecha actual, pero no se como sacar una fecha próxima, como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Qué sería **indefinidamente**? ¿Hasta el final de los tiempos? Vas a necesitar mucha memoria RAM para almacenar esa información.

Comment: No se almacenara, es ilustrativo como fecha limite

Comment: Puedes usar la función getDay() para días de la semana. Esta función devuelve 1 si el día es lunes (0, si es domingo, 1 si es lunes, 2 si es martes...). Para escribir archivos, puedes usar el método writeFile(). Un saludo

Comment: @JakintsuIheslari el OP habla de un elemento `<input>` de tipo texto, por lo cual se asume que trabaja desde un navegador, por lo cual `writeFile` no tendría sentido. A ver qué argumenta el OP al respecto.

Comment: @cosito, te invito a repasar [ask] y [mcve]. Recuerda que las preguntas deben ser más específicas, mostrando lo que has intentado. Tal como está redactada tu pregunta parece que quieres que alguien lo haga por ti. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras lo raro es que en el título habla de un archivo txt, creo que el OP necesita formular bien su pregunta. También concuerdo contigo con la parte **indefinidamente**, ¿qué quiere decir esto? ¿cuáles serían las restricciones? Es decir, tomando su ejemplo, se ejcuta hoy martes, se toma el siguiente lunes y se guarda, pero, ¿qué pasa si se ejecuta mañana miércoles nuevamente? ¿se guarda la información nuevamente? ¿O es un proceso que se ejecutará una única vez y traerá todos los lunes hasta el final de los tiempos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que esto te servirá

- primero obtienes la fecha actual
- luego obtienes el numero de día de esta fecha (0=domingo, 1=lunes,...) y en caso de ser domingo cambias ese valor por 7
- luego teniendo en cuenta que hay 7 días en una semana le restas el numero del día actual
- ya para finalizar obtienes la fecha del día que deseas sumando a la fecha actual tu resultado anterior mas el numero del día al que quieres llegar en este caso 1=lunes

```js
var d = new Date();
         var Nday = (d.getDay() == 0)?7:d.getDay();       
         var SumDay = 7 - Nday;
         d.setDate(d.getDate() + SumDay + 1);
         console.log(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

También Con la librería moment js podemos obtener lo que requerís usando
isoWeekday() esta Obtiene o establece el día ISO
de la semana siendo 1 lunes y 7  domingo también se admite nombre del día de acuerdo a la configuración.
Comprobamos si el día requerido pertenece a la semana actual o a la próxima semana la cual se puede obtener mediante add() si quisiéramos conocer cuantos días faltan simplemente aplicamos diff().

```js
//npm install moment
var moment = require('moment')
let dia = 1
let proximoLunes = this.buscar(dia);
console.log('Fecha del Proximo Lunes!', proximoLunes.format("D MMMM YYYY"))
function buscar(dia) {
  const diaRequerido = dia;
  const hoy = moment().isoWeekday();
  
  if (hoy <= diaRequerido) {
    console.log(moment().isoWeekday(diaRequerido))
    return moment().isoWeekday(diaRequerido);
  } else {
    /*Si no pertenece a la semana actual ir a proxima semana */
    return moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(diaRequerido);
  }
}
```